# Put data inside of function (.text in C)

Tags: c, assembly, arm, x86-64

After profiling my code I optimized one of my functions and it didn't get any faster. I suspect the problem is because the data is constantly being kicked out of L1 cache. I want to try moving it into the instruction cache. Here's an example program. Test is tiny in both x64 and ARM8, much less than 64 bytes. Both gcc and clang put data in a separate location. Is there a way I can have the compiler put the data in the function/instruction cache?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int test(int n) {
    static const int data[]={ 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44};
    return data[n&3] < (n>>2);
}

int main( int argc, char*argv[]) {
    printf("%d is %d\n", argc, test(argc));
}
```

Comment: You cannot put data into the instruction cache.  The instruction cache is only used for fetching instructions.

Comment: You mean force the compiler to run `mov`-immediate instructions to store the data somewhere before reloading, so the load comes from store-forwarding regardless of cache hotness?  Perhaps better to just compute the data instead of using a lookup table at all.  `((n&3) + 1) * 0x11`.  https://godbolt.org/z/4M8Kvj43Y hmm, gcc and clang both use quite a lot of instructions, but not a crazy amount for x86-64.  But AArch64 is great. https://godbolt.org/z/1rE4sroKG

Comment: @PeterCordes clever solution. My real data is about 40 items that fit into 1 byte each and has maybe 3 or 4 patterns to it. Maybe I can add them together to avoid branches. I'll think about this. This example data was chosen so I can easily find it in objdump